# how to set height and width using innerhtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am setting  Height for the conatainer in c# Code

```
 public string Height34
        {
           get { return Convert.ToString(Settings["container"]); }
       }
```

I am reciving those values in ascx page like

```
height:<%= this.Height34 %>px;
```

When i run its getting error like

Error: DNAiusTwitter is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). ---> System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) at DotNetNuke.Modules.DNAiusTwitter.View.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\DNAius-3\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\DotNetNukeverticalsliding\DesktopModules\DNAiusTwitter\View.ascx.cs:line 123 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Because i am using

```
this.Controls.Add(scriptTagLinks);
```

Comment: Whose height are you setting? Why not set the Height property of that control?

Comment: how to set  height property.I am reciving values frm settngs page.

Comment: Every control has a [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.height.aspx) property.

Comment: You're more likely to get a response to your new questions if you accept answers to previous questions (if they have provided an answer).